# NSSavePanel - How to truncate navigation to one directory

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

The situation is simple, need to truncate navigation of an NSSavePanel to a single directory.

May be missing something but so far no luck.

Other than this all works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*This may not work on 10.9 (or later)*

Implement the delegate method `panel:didChangeToDirectoryURL:`, if the panel has changed to show a directory other than one of the ones it should use `setDirectoryURL:` to reset it.

By doing this you can constrain the panel to show a single directory, some sub-tree of the file system, etc.

*However* it is reported on the developer forums that `setDirectoryURL:` when running under the sandbox on 10.9 may not work from within (this?) delegate method - just does nothing.

On the upside *DefaultFolder* works under 10.9 in sandboxed apps, so if the above doesn't work somebody out there knows the answer...

Comment: That is a good approach, just thinking why didn't thought of this. As for the 10.9 sandbox, won't be a problem for now. So will mark this one as the right one and up vote it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it myself, but you could try the [`panel:validateURL:error:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/NSOpenSavePanelDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSOpenSavePanelDelegate/panel%3avalidateURL%3aerror%3a) delegate method.

Comment: The problem with that delegate call is that it only works when saving. My goal is to prevent the navigation entirely.